# Adding content to a file before the </head> tag

Tags: php, file

I want to add a link to a stylesheet just before the `</head>` tag in an HTML file.

The HTML file is created with:

```
$file = file_put_contents( $path, $HTMLcontent );
```

Any PHP function to achieve it?

Comment: Are you trying to add a link to a stylesheet ? or ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `str_replace` function:

`str_replace('</head>', '<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head>', $html);`

Comment: Definitively it is easier to add the content into the string instead of the file. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There exists no built-in function for this purpose. One possible solution will be to get the contents of the file with [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument), find the `<head>` tag and then add `<style>` tag as a child and set the required attributes. Once you've done that, you can use [`DOMDocument::save()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php) to save the file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but definitively it's easier to do this stuff with the string.

Comment: @ManoloSalsas: It's easier. But optimal? No.

Comment: All right, I'll try. I have to use `DOMDocument::loadHTML($content)` before. Isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say: `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile($file)`

Comment: @ManoloSalsas: Correct. `loadHTMLFile()` would work. Alternatively, you can fetch the contents first using `file_get_contents()` or similar, and then use `loadHTML()`.